# Update datetime values to same date but persist time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm in a situation where I would like to update the date of all the values in the table to have the same *day* but persist the *time* of each record.

```
So these three dates...
8/28/2012 14:00:00
8/28/2010 12:00:00
8/28/2008 10:00:00

Should be turned into...
8/28/2012 14:00:00
8/28/2012 12:00:00
8/28/2012 10:00:00

UPDATE MySpecialTable
SET DateField = {...?};
```

**Edit:**  Regardless of the day the date is on (i.e. 8/28/2012, 1/1/2012, 4/1/2012, etc), I want to persist the time and *mass update* all the day/month/year to a specific value.

Comment: the dates are today, right? is that the requirement? is this a one-off, or is this a process that you will need to repeat? if the latter, will the date always be '2012-08-28' or will it always be "today."

Comment: I would also specify in your requirements if you are trying to only update the rows that fall on Aug. 28th of any year, or if you're trying to update *all* rows to show their persisted time as Aug. 28th of this year.

Answer (score 6):

```
DECLARE @Target DATETIME;
SET @Target = '20120828';

-- if the date is supposed to be today rather than hard-coded or parameterized:

-- SET @Target = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, '19000101', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), '19000101');

UPDATE dbo.MySpecialTable
  SET DateField = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, DateField, @Target), DateField);
```

This will work if the target date is before or after the value in the column.

Also, if you only care about time, you should consider using the [TIME data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) (SQL 2008+). This will make it easy to apply any date you want to the data at query time, without having to actually perform any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, assuming you are using SQL Server 2008 or greater:

```
update MySpecialTable
    set DateField = cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) + (DateField - cast(DateField as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (updated to have the same date):

```
DECLARE @myDate DATETIME
SET @myDate = '2012-08-28T00:00:00.000'
UPDATE [MySpecialTable]
   SET [DateField] = DATEADD(Day, 0-DATEDIFF(Day, 0, [DateField]), [DateField]) + @myDate
```

- `DATEADD(Day, 0-DATEDIFF(Day, 0, [DateField]), [DateField])` gets the
  timestamp and makes the date to the min value (1/1/1900)
- Add the above to the desired date in the variable

Comment: This will not update the date if any of the rows are not on the same date in a different year.

Comment: You are right. I realized that as soon as I submitted the answer. Will update it.

Comment: I'd also be careful with `YYYY-MM-DD` - try that with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;` for example (there are many other cases where it will break).

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd is compliant to the international ISO 8601 standard for dates. Setting language to French or anything did not break the result. As long as yyyy is interpreted as year, SQL Server ignores all culture settings. Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx) link

Comment: I don't think you tried it. It breaks for me, since yyyy-mm-dd is actually interpreted as yyyy-dd-mm in that language. Whether it conforms to ISO 8601 or not is a different issue: what is more relevant is that SQL Server does not obey ISO 8601 in all cases, so don't assume that following ISO 8601 will always yield infallible code.

Comment: Also the link you provided specifies something very explicit. `YYYY-MM-DD` <> `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS`. The string in your answer breaks unless you add `T00:00:00`.

Comment: Omg! You are right. Great catch. Updated my answer. We should have a question & answer on this.